# Want to tag runs

Tags: vba, tags, powerpoint

I need to tag a TextRange (specifically a TextRange returned by Runs() ), but VBA in PowerPoint only allows you to tag presentations, slides, and shapes.

Working my way back up the object tree (run > TextRange > textframe > items > shapes), I discover that shapes are the closest taggable object.

I could do the tagging in the shape that contains the run, but I need a way to uniquely identify the run.

For instance, I could envision tagging the shape with key=unique_id_of_the_run, value=whatever, but I don’t know of anyway in VBA to get a unique for a run.

If there was a way to get a unique I’d (or memory address) of objects in general, I could use that as my unique key, but I don’t know how to get an object’s unique is in VBA.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Runs are properties, not objects. They don't carry any unique identifier in their XML. A textbox or shape can have a unique identifier, but doesn't always. As an example, PowerPoint 2019 normally creates text boxes with an extLst tag that contains 2 GUIDs. PowerPoint 2007 doesn't. Shapes have an id number that is unique to that shape on that slide, though you can't read that directly with VBA. To do serious work with Office XML, VBA is not the right tool. The OpenXML SDK with VB or C# could get you the id of the shape.

Comment: The exact run is subject to change whenever the formatting of text in the textrange changes (e.g. user bolds one word). Assuming you understand that and aren't concerned, couldn't you tag the shape with Tags.Add "Run", "42" ... ie, the 42nd run in the shape's textrange? Knowing that, you can, for example, change the text for that run. Changing its formatting would get messy.